# HostedNetwork get current number of clients

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm making a small batch script for my (win10) computer to reset "hostednetwork" every N minutes if the number of clients is 0. For this I'm going to use Task Scheduler, but I need to check inside the script for the number of clients.

I know running `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` shows me a list of information including this value. I've seen there is some `setting=<value>` argument for that, but there is no documentation else than `setting=security`...

I also tried to use `findstr` but I couldn't work it out. However, I figured that even if I got it to work, I wouldn't know how to save the value into a variable for comparing...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some lookup I found that using `find` I can even compare it...

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork | find "Number of clients" | find "0" > nul && goto start || goto stop

start:
echo "There are clients :)"
exit

stop:
echo "There are zero clients :("
exit
```

Comment: Just to make you aware that the answer above would treat, for instance, `109` or `20` clients, as zero too, and would not yield the required action.

Comment: @Compo oh! In my case it wouldn't be a problem because I'm using this only to know if I'm connected (I'm the only one that uses my network)... But, for other people, can you answer with the correct way instead?